# Guidelines for how deep to nest BEM style class names

Tags: css, bem

I got introduced to BEM by a recommendation to another question I asked here on SO, and have found in so valuable. After a year of using it, I often find myself having deep nested levels of composition. e.g.

```css
.abc__main
.abc__main__card
.abc__main__card__item
.abc__main__card__item__heading
.abc__main__card__item__icon
.abc__main__card__item__text
.abc__main__card__item__text__em
.abc__main__card__item__text__em--green
```

Im pretty sure the point of BEM is to break away from composition, but I seem to lock myself into it. I have read the [BEM website](http://getbem.com/), but feel I must be missing something.

Is there some sort of guideline to help know how one should compose an item?

E.g. should I break it apart like this (With the help of @Chris Pickford suggestion):

```css
.abc__main

.abc__card

.abc__item
.abc__item__heading
.abc__item__icon
.abc__item__text
.abc__item__text__em
.abc__item__text__em--green
```

EDIT: Thanks to Chris's answer I just had a realisation thats its not called BEEM, or BEEEM, but simply BEM, there should only ever be one nested element inside the block.

Comment: Wouldn't card be it's own block? Why are you nesting them?

Comment: Hmm, thats a good point, why, because I have always just nested everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should completely flatten your block structure to use BEM convention.

It might look something like this:

```
.abc {}
.abc__main {}
.card {}
.card__item {}
.card__heading {}
.card__icon {}
.card__text {}
.card__text--em {}
.card__text--green {}
```

It's in the FAQ here: http://getbem.com/faq/#css-nested-elements

Comment: That makes sense. sorry I forgot to mention, abc is a global unique acronym to ensure it doesnt have the same name as another class

Comment: Orginally I had `em` as a sub component of `text`, i.e. likely a span. So I imagine it would be .card__em and .card__em--green ?